# Send Messages to Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, wireless, screen, internet

I want to build a gift, similar to the [Heartbox](https://en.lovebox.love/) with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1.

My simpler Version will just be the Raspberry Pi with a screen attached to it anywhere in the world with a wifi-connection. I would like to send something (First text maybe latern an Image) through an app or website and it will be displayed.

Do you maybe have some input for me on how I could tackle this task? Anything helps! And please tell me, if this was the wrong network to ask, I was unsure.

Comment: None of the Stack Exchange is the right place for such questions. You're expected to come here knowing what you want to do, with a specific issue you stumbled upon.

Comment: Perhaps start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is too long for a comment...

This is more 'how do I develop a product' rather than the Pi stack Exchange (hence my close vote) but to give you a way to start I would break it down into steps:

1. Find yourself an enclosure - that dictates everything in this case (sorry)
2. Find a screen that fits into the case and connects to the Pi
3. Learn how to display messages on the screen - [PyGame](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/retro-gaming) is handy for sprites etc
4. Learn how to get data via a web site running on a Pi (look at [Flask for Python](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) for example)
5. Learn how to start that program at power on
6. Learn how to turn on and off a motor for the heart - intro robotic kits can help (look at the Cam Jam kits for a gentle intro to electronics / sensors / robotics)
7. Merge that into the web program
8. Squeeze it into the box

Also - consider what happens when you need to turn it off - microcontrollers are fine if the power is pulled - Linux can get upset. Maybe the Pi is not the platform you need (well Raspbian OS - possibly [Tiny Core](http://www.tinycorelinux.net) would be better as it lives in memory)